# How to combine child_process.spawn output with async pipeline while handling errors?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, pipeline

How to combine `child_process.spawn` output with async `pipeline` while handling errors?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { pipeline }= require('stream/promises');
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const zlib = require('zlib');

async function run() {    
    try {
        // this works: const dump = spawn('node', ['-v']);
        const dump = spawn('nodeeeeeeeeeeeeeee', ['-v']); // how to handle error here?

        await pipeline(
            dump.stdout, // I thought it's possible to just put `dump` here without .stdout
            zlib.createGzip(),
            fs.createWriteStream('node-version.gz')
        );
        console.log('Pipeline succeeded');
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('errrrr', err)
    }
}

run().catch(console.error);
```

Is there any elegant way to make `spawn` suitable for pipeline? (Without memory leaks, uncleaned streams etc.)

Comment: Handle errors on the child process with `dump.on("error", ...)`.